# Ошибка: Error connecting with ssl. Eof was observed that violates the protocol

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy

я пытаюсь получить данные с сайта `https://exergy.skmenergy.com`
Вот мой код настройки инди компонента

```
FHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  FSSLIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  FSSLIOHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
  FSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
  FSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  FSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];

  FCookie := TIdCookieManager.Create(nil);

  with FHttp do
  begin
    IOHandler := FSSLIOHandler;
    CookieManager := FCookie;
    AllowCookies := True;
    HandleRedirects := True;
    Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    if StrToBoolDef(FParam.Items['ProxyUse'], True) = True then
    begin
      ProxyParams.ProxyPort := StrToInt(FParam.Items['Port']);
      ProxyParams.ProxyServer := FParam.Items['Server'];
      ProxyParams.ProxyUsername := FParam.Items['Login'];
      ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := FParam.Items['ProxyPassword'];
    end;
    ReadTimeout := 100000000;
  end;
```

Но после вызова

```
FHTTP.Get('https://exergy.skmenergy.com);
```

Получаю ошибку.
`Error connecting with ssl. eof was observed that violates the protocol.`
Что я делаю не так?

Файлы `libeay32.dll` и `ssleay32.dll` находятся рядом. Их версии достаточное новые (`1.1.0.4`)  Версия `Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10.2 Version 25.0.29039.2004`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Их версии достаточное новые (1.1.0.4)

Вот в этом, по-видимому, и проблема, т.к. Indy [не поддерживает OpenSSL 1.1.xx](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183).

Вам нужно использовать OpenSSL версии 1.0.2 https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries

Comment: Да , действительно. Это сработало. Спасибо огромное!